# ui-responsive grid wraps the columns into rows jQuery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, grid, jquery-mobile-grid

Trying to create a responsive grid which supports mobile screens. When using jQuery mobile `ui-responsive` grid, the column wraps and behaves like rows(one below one) even-though the first row has space accommodate second column. If I test the same in Tablet size screens, things works fine. Where I am wrong or this is how it behaves ?

The code I used is

```
<div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <a href="#" id="link_frgt_pswd" data-inline="true" >Forgot Password ?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a href="#" id="btn-submit" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Login</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <h3>For Member </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a href="#" id="link_unlock_acc" data-inline="true" >Unlock Account</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <h3>For Provider </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <a href="#" id="btn-provider" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I even tried to reduce the width of columns with css `.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a { width: 30% } .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b { width: 30% }`. it reduces the width but still `ui-block-b` remains in the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ui-responsive class in jQM adds a CSS media query for a max-width of 560px. So any time the screen is less than 560px, the columns are stacked. If you want your own custom break point, instead of ui-responsive, make your own class name and set your desired break point.

For example, if you want the stacking to happen only when screen width is below 300px:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a my-breakpoint">...</div>

@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
    .my-breakpoint .ui-block-a,
    .my-breakpoint .ui-block-b,
    .my-breakpoint .ui-block-c,
    .my-breakpoint .ui-block-d,
    .my-breakpoint .ui-block-e {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yw321mps/)**

You can also look at this demo from the jQM site:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids-custom-responsive/